# node.js / Express throws 'RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded' under high load

Tags: javascript, node.js, garbage-collection, express, stack-overflow

We are having an issue with our node environment running under high
load that we have not been able to find the source of.

A little background: we are running a clustered node application using
Express for the http framework.  Currently, there are 3 boxes with 8
CPU cores on each, and each box is running a cluster of 6 node
workers.  The setup seems to work great and I've researched all the
suggested methodologies such that I believe the setup is solid. We're
running node.js 0.8.1 with Express 2.5.11 and XMLHttpRequest 1.4.2.

Here's the issue: We're doing a "dark launch" test of this product
(i.e. the browser client code has javascript ajax calls to our APIs in
the background, but is not used on the page or shown to the user).  After a few minutes running successfully, the system is throwing:

```
[RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded]
```

We're catching the error with the 'uncaughtException' event in the
cluster controller (which starts each worker), however there is no
stack trace available at that level.  I've done extensive research on
this issue and can't seem to find anyone with a similar error.  After
combing through EVERY line of code in the system, here's what I know:

- I cannot find any recursion or circular references.  (I've read that
  this error doesn't always mean a recursion problem, but we've checked;
  we've actually run tests by removing most of the code anyways and it
  still happens, see below);
- I've gone down to 1 worker process per box to try and eliminate the
  cluster as an issue -- the problem still happens;
- The problem ONLY happens under high load.  Our traffic is approx.
  1500 pages per second and, during heavy traffic times, can reach 15000
  pages per second (we haven't been able to replicate on a dev
  environment);
- The timing of the error being caught varies, but is usually within 15 minutes;
- The error does NOT seem to impact operation!  By this, I mean that
  there are no corrupt responses and, aside from the occasional timeout,
  the system never crashes;
- The worker process that traps the error recovers and starts serving
  requests again after a few seconds;
- I have gotten the error to happen on the most basic design--no
  additional APIs are called.  Simply take a request and respond with a
  simple json response.  This is the most curious part.  It doesn't seem
  like the system is failing in any of my code -- It's failing without
  instantiating any of the classes to do the *real* work.  Obviously, I
  started out with more code, but slowly took out pieces until it was
  still failing under a bare-bones setup.

The most telling symptom, I believe, is that the error always happens
AFTER a request has been fully served.  That is, the server takes a
request, finds the proper Express route, calls res.send, and is
finished.  This really feels like garbage collection to me!  I've read
that the V8 engine has a very good GC engine, but I'm wondering how
much our heavy load is impacting things.

As I said, the code throws the error even on a basic design.  Having
taken out most of our custom code, this is the basics of the setup.
Sorry that I'm cutting here, so not all variable declarations etc will
be included, however the code does work and all that stuff is in the
real code:

**Cluster controller.  This is a cleaned-up version of what is started on the command line.**

```
cluster = require('cluster');
path = require('path');
fs = require('fs');
app = require('./nodeApi');
_ = require('underscore');
nodeUtil = require(./nodeUtil);

process.on('uncaughtException', function(err) {
  var stamp;
  stamp = new Date();
  console.log("***************************** Exception Caught, " + stamp);
  return console.log("Exception is:", err);
});

if (cluster.isMaster) {
  if ((nodeUtil.isLiveServer() || nodeUtil.isCluster()) && process.env.IS_CLUSTER !== '0') {
    numCPUs = require("os").cpus().length - 2;
    if (numCPUs <= 0) {
      numCPUs = 1;
    }
  } else {
    numCPUs = 1;
  }
  console.log("Forking " + numCPUs + " workers...");
  for (i = _i = 1; 1 <= numCPUs ? _i <= numCPUs : _i >= numCPUs; i = 1 <= numCPUs ? ++_i : --_i) {
    worker = cluster.fork();
  }
} else {
  app.start();
}
```

**nodeWorker code.**  Using Express and a simple route to serve a
request.  Request is wrapped in a callback if jsonp is used (for our
testing with ajax, this was needed)

```
(function() {
  var crypto, express, fs, modroot, path, staticroot, _;
  express = require('express');
  _ = require('underscore');
  fs = require('fs');
  path = require('path');

  module.exports.start = function() {
    logFile = fs.createWriteStream("" + logpath + "/access.log", {
      flags: 'a'
    });

    app = express.createServer();

    app.configure(function() {
      app.use(express.logger({
        stream: logFile,
        format: ':remote-addr - [:date] - ":method :url HTTP/:http-version" :status :res[content-length] ":referrer" :response-time ms'
      }));
      app.use(express.errorHandler({
        dumpExceptions: true,
        showStack: true
      }));
      app.use(express.cookieParser());
      app.use(express.bodyParser());
      app.use(express.session({
        secret: "ourMemStoreSecret",
        cookie: {
          domain: ".ourdomain.com"
        },
        maxAge: new Date(Date.now() + 7200000),
        // The store WAS a redis store.  I took it out to eliminate redis as the issue.  We don't use sessions anyway.
        store: new require('express').session.MemoryStore({
          reapInterval: 60000 * 15
        })
      }));
      app.use(express["static"](staticroot));
      app.set('view engine', 'underscore');  // For our template rendering.  Not used in this test.
      app.set('views', __dirname + '/views/src');
      app.set('view options', {
        layout: false
      });
      app.use(app.router);
    });

    ignore = function(req, res, next) {
      if (req.params.api === 'favicon.ico') {
        return next('route');
      }
      return next();
    };

    wrapCallback = function(req, res, next) {
      var callbackName;
      if (callbackName = req.query.callback) {
        req.wrapCallback = true;
        res._send = res.send;
        res.send = function(data, status) {
          var dataString;
          if (_.isObject(data)) {
            dataString = encodeURI(JSON.stringify(data));
            res.setHeader('Content-Type', 'application/javascript');
            return res._send("" + callbackName + "(\"" + dataString + "\")", status);
          } else {
            data = encodeURI(data);
            return res._send("" + callbackName + "(\"" + data + "\")", status);
          }
        };
      }
      return next();
    };

    app.error(function(err, req, res, next) {
      console.log("[" + process.pid + "] Error Handler. Ok.", err);
      return res.send({
        error: err.msg
      }, err.statusCode);
    });

    // Does anyone know how to hard-code a path AND put it into a variable at the same time?
    // Kind of like: "/:api=MyTestAPI"  ??  That's why this route is here.
    setAPIName = function(req, res, next) {
      req.params.api = 'MyTestAPI';
      return next();
    };
    app.get("/MyTestAPI", setAPIName, wrapCallback, function(req, res) {
      res.send({
        hello: 'world'
      }, 200);
      return console.log("[" + process.pid + "] res.send (no cacher) is done");
    });

    process.setMaxListeners(0);
    process.send({
      // For IPC - the controller has a handler for this message
      cmd: 'isStarted'
    });
    return app.listen(process.env.APP_PORT);
  };

}).call(this);
```

**What the error looks like.**  Basically, I never see it happen in
the middle of a request.  There isn't a call stack on the error
either--it's only the stack overflow message.  Here you can see 2
worker processes each serving a response, then the error on one of
them.

```
[660] res.send (no cacher) is done
[654] res.send (no cacher) is done
***************************** Exception Caught, Fri Nov 02 2012 10:23:48 GMT-0400 (EDT)
```

I would really appreciate some feedback on this.  The system runs
beautifully and is capable of handling our huge traffic with 3 boxes.
The load on the boxes is about 40% and humming.  I'd love to find the
source of this issue so others can be as proud of this system as I am,
and show the node.js non-believers that this is a great product!

Comment: `console.log` the error with `err.stack`: `console.log(err.stack);` SO you can see the stack trace. Also can try using [longjohn](https://github.com/mattinsler/longjohn) to get long stack traces.

Comment: Could you elaborate on why you do (1) res._send = res.send; (2) res.send = function(data, status) {...}, and then (3) res._send() from **within** res.send() ? Could this lead to a circular reference?

Comment: I appear to be having the same problem. Did you ever find a solution?

Comment: @HectorCorrea: it would appear that `_send` is the original version of `send` and that `send` has been replaced with an upgraded version to do some other things and then call the original. There doesn't appear to be any unintended recursion there.

Comment: `res._send = res._send || res.send;` to ensure that you are not wrapping more than once. Also change coffee-script style `for` loop to flat `for` loop while forking. Could post a bug to nodejs as well if other people are getting this error. Could be related to Linux kernel and sockets: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13770826/poorly-balanced-socket-accepts-with-linux-3-2-kernel-vs-2-6-kernel

Comment: Thank you all for your posts!  Yes, the _send method was intentionally wrapped so that we could detect when to add a callback for jsonp.  I realize now that jsonp has is handled automatically in version 3, so this is no longer needed!  See my answer below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I thought I would update my own post to explain what the fix was for me.

After realizing that I had done everything else I knew how to do, the solution presented itself by doing this:

**Install Express version 3**

There were so many differences and changes that needed to be made to the core code that it took me a full day just to do the conversion.  However, in doing so, I was able to take advantage of many new v3 featuers including the .param method for attaching helpers to your :param variables in each route.  This eliminated several of my old "helper" functions, so instead of chaining through the routes, I used that instead.

I now have a full understanding of routes/middleware, and simply by re-writing for Express v3, my problem went away!

Since this isn't an exact answer, these are the things I used to learn how to make the conversion:

[Express v3 API reference](http://expressjs.com/api.html)

[Information on how routes work](https://github.com/senchalabs/connect)

[Awesome HOWTO doc!  Thanks to those guys!](https://github.com/visionmedia/express/wiki/Migrating-from-2.x-to-3.x)

Answer (score 3):

I have faced same problem in one of my production environment. During the analysis, I found following things, may be i am wrong. But I hope, this will help you...

This problem is basically associated with Socket. There is a option how many open Socket connection should accept? and can the connection keep in half open?.

Normally this kind of exceptions happen only because of how frequent you hit server in particular time period.

Let me explain clearly...

1. Let assume there is only two socket path and you have four request each should take 5 seconds of processing time.
2. In general NodeJs can serve perfectly when you give 2 request in 0th second and remaining 2 in 6th second.
3. Rather than like this, if you give 4 request in 0th second, then NodeJs ready to serve 2 request only. NodeJs is simply close socket for remaining two request.
   Note: Later if you give the same request, NodeJs will accept and give the response.
4. For more information, please go through socket.io.js implementation.

And my solution is,

1. Create load balancer in server friendly way.
2. Run the NodeJs instances or clusters under the load balancer.

Or If you find any other easy way to solve this, Please update this post...

I am waiting to know a great solution for this problem.

Thanks

Comment: Thanks for the reply!  This will be good to know going forward since the architecture isn't changing.  We are running a load balanced environment via nginx, and node itself is also clustered with 'cluster'.